# cx_Freeze not including all modules in library

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

So I'm trying to compile a python script named "File.py" using this code:

```
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    # Define packages needed(not builtin)
    packages = ['scipy' , 'numpy']
    options = {
        'build_exe': {
            'packages': packages,
        },
    }

    setup(name='Monitor',
          version = '0.8',
          description = 'Monitors stuff.',
          options = options,
          executables = [Executable("File.py")])
```

"File.py" only uses scipy and numpy, which I have included in the packages variable. However, after compiling and running File.exe, I get the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree'". I am using python 3.6 and cx_Freeze 6 (which supports python 3.6). How can I get cx_Freeze to include all of the necessary modules?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the actual address of the library. So find where the scipy and numpy files are and in the packages, include something like this: `r"C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
r"C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll",`

Comment: That's for tkinter.  Not scipy.  But still your on the right path.

Comment: I was just using code that I've used before as an example

Comment: Oh OK fine. It was just in case you didn't know.

Comment: I specified the file path to the module using
packages = ['scipy' , 'numpy',r"C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"]
Unfortunately, it still couldn't find the module.

Answer (score 0):

Probably dead, but I'll put in my two cents having encountered a couple issues like this with scipy over the years in combination with cx_Freeze. I had trouble finding documentation of this issue on SO.

First, when you run File.exe, check the full stack trace in the dialog box when you get the error. ModuleNotFoundError is your symptom, but root cause is in which file is attempting to load the module, usually an __init__.py file somewhere in scipy.

Second, go to that file and compare the module name being loaded against the package name and aliases. You are looking for discrepancies in the case of the module name or path to the module. For example, one ckdtree load issue I have come across was __init__.py was attempting to load 'ckdtree', but the module in the distribution was 'cKDTree' or had a capital letter where there wasn't supposed to be one. Changing the case in the file attempting to load the module fixes the issue.